# Estructura del programa, como relacionar estas dos clases

Tags: java

Por un lado tengo la clase Asignatura:

```
public class Assignatura{
    private int codi;
    private Assignatura seguent;

    public Assignatura(int c){
        codi=c;
        seguent=null;
    }
```

Como podeis observar el atributo siguiente apuntará a otra asignatura, para poder así tener una estructura dinámica. Lo mismo ocurre con la clase Curso:

```
public class Curs {
    private int codi;
    private Curs seguent;       

    public Curs(int c, llista_assignatura_curs ll){
        codi=c;
        seguent=null;
    }
```

Mi objetivo ahora es que un curso tenga una lista de asignaturas, para ello he creado la clase 'llista_asignatura_curs':

```
public class llista_assignatura_curs {
private Assignatura primera;


public llista_assignatura_curs(){
    primera=null;
}
```

Esta clase tiene métodos para añadir y eliminar asignaturas de la lista. El problema es que ahora. Necesito saber como vincular una lista a un curso. ¿Sería añadir un atributo a la clase curso del tipo 'llista_assignatura_curs' la solución? ¿O hay otra manera mejor? Gracias

PD: esta sería mi propuesta, pero creo que se puede hacer mejor

```
public class Curs {
    private int codi;
    private Curs seguent;
    private llista_assignatura_curs llista;

    public Curs(int c, llista_assignatura_curs ll){
        codi=c;
        seguent=null;
        llista= ll;
    }
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si no he entendio mal lo que necesitas es que la clase Curso, contenga una lista de Asignaturas. Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras:

Si necesitas la clase `llista_assignatura_curs`, ya lo haces bien, pero deberás crear una lista de Asignaturas porqué ahora mismo solo estás guardando una asignatura por lista:

```
public class llista_assignatura_curs {
    private ArrayList<Assignatura> lista = new ArrayList();
```

Si no, también puedes directamente crear en la clase Curso, la lista de asignaturas, y en la clase Curso tener los metodos para añadir, eliminar, modificar asignaturas:

```
public class Curs {
    private ArrayList<Assignatura> lista = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero si te fijas en 'llista_assignatura_curs' aunque solo guarde una asignatura puedo acceder a todas las demás con el campo 'seguent'. Lo que necesito, por ejemplo, es si quiero añadir una asignatura a un determinado curso, acceder a dicha lista del curso y añadirla con el correspondiente método. El problema en sí está en como relaciono la lista con la clase curso. Lo que sí tengo claro es que tanto la lista como curso, deben ser independientes. La cosa más 'independiente' que se me ocurre es simplemente poner la lista como atributo en curso.

Comment: Pero como lo tienes hecho, solo podrás añadir una asignatura por curso, ya que la lista solo contiene una asignatura, y cada curso solo tiene una lista por mucho que puedas acceder a todas las asignaturas con `seguent`(Que por otro lado no entiendo muy bien la funcionalidad o el sentido de `seguent`) solo puedes añadir una asignatura a una lista, y una lista a un curso.

Answer (score 0):

la solucion a tu problema es adicionar un atributo de tipo asignatura en curso, así:

```
public class Curs {
    private int codi;
    private Curs seguent;       
    private Assignatura asignatura;
    public Curs(int c, llista_assignatura_curs ll){
        codi=c;
        seguent=null;
        asignatura = null;
    }
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que estas simulando el funcionamiento de una lista de listas y debido a que estas manejando relaciones reflexivas, utilizar recursividad te va a facilitar mucho tu trabajo.

Comment: Gracias por responder!!